# How to draw piechart in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I need to draw a pie chart in python using seaborn or matplotlib.
How to draw pie chart having values:-
x=27, y = 2421 in python.

Please help me with this.
[Like shown in img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9TI0.png)

Comment: Please help yourself first. [ask]

Comment: Does this help? https://pythontic.com/visualization/charts/piechart#:~:text=Drawing%20a%20simple%20Pie%20Chart%20using%20Python%20Matplotlib,in%20a%20pie%20chart%20in%20counter%20clockwise%20direction.

Answer (score 1):

while giving the values of x=27 and y=2421 it will give output in rectangle format , so i suggest you to write this code and in output you will get the adjusting button there you can try all the buttons and adjust it according to your comfortability.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

activities = ['eat', 'sleep', 'work', 'play']

slices = [3, 7, 8, 6]

colors = ['r', 'y', 'g', 'b']

plt.pie(slices, labels = activities, colors=colors, startangle=90, shadow = True, explode=(0, 0, 0.1, 0), 

radius = 1.2, autopct = '%1.1f%%') 

plt.legend() 

plt.show()
```

You can refer this blog - http://zetcode.com/python/python-matplotlib/

Comment: Thank you @Zeeking786. But I have calculated this values from excel data...like x is the count of one column and y is the sum of other column